# how to dump (print) an OSDictionary to the console / log?

Tags: debugging, macos, kernel, iokit

I would like to inspect the contents of an OSDictionary from my kext.
is there a convenient way to print the contents to system.log or similar?
(ala CFShow()) ?

thx->adv,

|K<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a code-snippet to assist in this (which prints the dict keys):

```
static void printDictionaryKeys (OSDictionary * inDictionary, char * inMsg)
```

the source is here:
[printDictionaryKeys()](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/iokit/Kernel/IOPlatformExpert.cpp?txt)